# NET: Implementation in C#

Tags: networking, ip

I have a router that runs on two VM. The second VM has IP address of 9.1.2.2
I have look [IP address overview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81350/private-ip-address-ranges),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Private networks should use private network addresses like 192.168.x or 10.x.  It is not a good idea to use a public IP address that has not been assigned to you.  At this moment reverse DNS seems to say that 9.1.2.2 is unassigned but that doesn't make it safe to use.

Comment: 9.0.0.0/8 is assigned to IBM.

Comment: @duskwuff - Thanks.  I thought it odd that the lookup returned no data.